# Make new variable based on final cumulative sum of another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to create a new variable that:

- summarises the count of one column
- then assigns a rank to the group according to the highest count in ascending order
- and if two (or more) cummulative counts are the same, it assigns it
  the next number.

Here's a test tibble:

```
df.test <- tibble(
  "group"  = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4),
  "score" = c(0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2)
)
```

and this is what I would like it to look like:

```
# A tibble: 11 x 4
   group score cum.score  rank
   <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     0         0     1
 2     1     2         2     1
 3     2     1         1     4
 4     2     3         4     4
 5     2     2         6     4
 6     3     2         2     3
 7     3     1         3     3
 8     2     2         8     4
 9     2     0         8     4
10     1     0         2     1
11     4     2         2     2
```

Note that group 4 was assigned rank 2 as it had the same score as group 1 who was assigned rank 1.

This is the closest I got (which is not close):

```
df.test %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(cum.score = cumsum(score),
         rank = last(cum.score))
```

but the `rank` just ascribes the total to them all instead of an actual rank.

Comment: Not clear how the `rank` is changed

Comment: Both groups 1 and 4 seem to have a max cum.score of 2. How did you decide who is rank 1 vs 2?

Comment: @akrun The `rank` would be determined by the max `cum.score` and then copied across all the rows of the same `group`.

Comment: @MrFlick I don't mind which comes first, it's just important that they are different and less than those of higher rank (instead of both 1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be to calculate the groups ranks in a sub-table and join that back to the original. You can do that with

```
df.test %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(cum.score = cumsum(score)) %>% {
    x <- .
    x %>% summarize(max = max(cum.score)) %>% 
    mutate(rank=rank(max, ties.method ="first"), max=NULL) %>% 
    left_join(x, .)
  }
```

This seems necessary because you want values assigned within-group but you want the rank assigned across-groups.

Comment: That's a very nice solution! I wasn't aware you could add in a sub-table within the pipes.

Answer (score 2):

I realise this is tagged with `dplyr`, but since there's already a good `dplyr` solution I'll add a `data.table` version.

In `data.table` you can join two tables `a` and `b`, adding a column of `b` (say `b$x`) to `a` with `a[b, on = .(somevar), x := i.x]`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df.test)

df.test[, cum.score := cumsum(score), group]
df.test[df.test[, max(cum.score), group][, V1 := frank(V1, ties.method = 'first')]
        , on = .(group), rank := i.V1]

df.test
#     group score cum.score rank
#  1:     1     0         0    1
#  2:     1     2         2    1
#  3:     2     1         1    4
#  4:     2     3         4    4
#  5:     2     2         6    4
#  6:     3     2         2    3
#  7:     3     1         3    3
#  8:     2     2         8    4
#  9:     2     0         8    4
# 10:     1     0         2    1
# 11:     4     2         2    2
```

Answer (score 2):

First define `cum.score` within group.  Also define `rank` within group as a logical variable which is TRUE for the last value.  Then outside of the grouping rank the last `cum.score` values using NA for the values other than last within group, i.e. those values assigned FALSE in the prior step.  Finally in a second grouping fill the NAs with the rank for that group.

```
df.test %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(cum.score = cumsum(score), rank = 1:n() == n()) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(rank = replace(NA * score, rank, rank(cum.score[rank], ties = "first"))) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(rank = na.omit(rank)) %>%
  ungroup
```